# How to overwrite a virtual method defined in a class in another class which is inside a function in C++

Tags: c++

I have a `class A` which is in a separate file(`sayfile1.cpp`)

```
class A{
public:
      virtual int add(){
      int a=5;
      int b=4;
      int c = a+b;
      return c;
      }
};
```

Now in a different file(say `file2.cpp`), i have a function(i have a many other things in this function) inside which i want to create a class inherited from `class A` and implement the virtual method declared in `class A`.

```
void function(Mat param1, Mat param2)
{
  //Some process here..
  ..
  ..
  int c=100;
  class B:public A{
  public:
        virtual int add(){

        return c;
        }
  };

}
```

Now if i were to call the function `int add()`, i want the result of `c` to be 100 and not 9.

Is it possible to do something like this in C++ ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define member variable:

```
class B: public A {
    int c_;
public:
    explicit B(int c):c_(c){};
    virtual int add() {
        return c_;
    }
}
B variable((100));
```

Comment: wat is the 'variable' u used ? i am tring to implement the same logic for a return type of IplImage* for Opencv and i am facing problems with this'variable' term
i am new to c++. so please bear with me.

Comment: When i use this logic for IplImage* instead of int, i get this error- "Object of abstract class type “B” is not allowed".
Any suggestions to ovecome this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your `file1.cpp` into `file1.h`:

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
class A {
public:
  virtual int add();
};
#endif
```

and `file1.cpp` with it's implementation:

```
int A::add { /*your code * }
```

In the other file you include only the header file:

```
#include "file1.h"
```

The following is not legal in C++:

```
void function(Mat param1, Mat param2)
{
  //Some process here..
  ..
  ..
  int c=100;
  class B:public A {
  public:
    virtual int add(){

    return c;
    }
 };
```

}

Instead, you need something like this:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B(int v) : c(v) {}
    virtual int add(){ return c; }
private:
    int c;
};

void function(Mat param1, Mat param2)
{
  //Some process here..
  ..
  ..
  int c=100;
  B o(c);
```

}

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. I do not understand everything here but when i tried debugging, the code went from

B o(c)
to 

class B : public A {

public:
 
 ->B(int v) : c(v) {}
    virtual int add(){ return c; }

private:
    int c;
};

and then it breaks out of the loop. I wanted the value of c to be passed to virtual int add() function defined in the next step

Comment: i am sorry. this i am new to this community and i don know how to type these comments in an organized way!

i meant the code went to B(int v) : c(v) {} and went out of the class to line after B o(c)